# Can interactions be both Cabibbo suppressed and allowed?

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, weak-interaction

Concerning the decay of the $K^+$ meson as shown in picture. I am restricting the analysis to the first two generations of quarks. As far as I understand, Cabibbo suppressed decays occur at $W$-vertices with either $u$-$s$ quarks or $c$-$d$ quarks, while Cabibbo allowed decays occur at W-vertices with either u-d quarks or c-s quarks. In the decay in the picture, the first w-vertex contains u-s quarks (anti-quarks in this case) and would thus be suppressed, while the second w-vertex involves u-d quarks and would thus be allowed. Is the overall reaction then both allowed and suppressed or is it just suppressed? I think I may have got something wrong. Can you only talk about allowed/suppressed decays in semi-leptonic decays, where only one quark-W vertex exists?

[image: K+-meson decay example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would classify as 'suppressed'

If both vertices are c-d or s-u a process is called 'doubly suppressed'.  For an example see https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.06222